# Spring MVC Controller to JSP table mapping

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application based on spring mvc framework.In this application there is menu bar and a single jsp page which contains number of html tables.Under different option I have to show different html tables with different header.

Current Way of implementing it.

JSP page contains different table under a single divison and they are seperated by  tag of JSTL.

In the href tag of menubar option I am passing values in this manner

```
out.println("<li><a  href=\"data?optionId="+menuOptId+"/"+key+"/"+menuDesc+" \"  ><span>"+menuDesc+"</span></a></li>");
```

Here in the href I am defining the ID/menuDesc and I am passing this value in the controller.In controller on the basis of ID I am fetching it data from database.

and on the basis of String comparison on menuDesc I am assigning an integere value and setting this the model.And in JSP on the basis of this model value I am showing that particular table

Here is the code snipet for that

Controller Code

```
model.addAttribute("table", attribute);
```

JSP Code

```
<c:if test="${table=='1'}">
<h3 align="center">${heading}</h3>
<br>

        <table align="center">
<thead class="color">
<tr>
```

But I don't like this string comparison and I was looking for some other option so that I can cutshort the dependency of String comparison.

Please suggest optimal way to do this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5pr0km9ul5o34f/fKmc9.png

Comment: Don't write HTML in Java. Don't write Java in HTML.

Comment: Create multiple jsps to render different tables. Pass the name of the jsp that contains the table you need from your controller to your main jsp. This way you can include any jsp in your main jsp during runtime without doing any comparisons.

Comment: You are asking me to pass a jsp page name.But currently I am passing a integer value on the basis of comparison.This comparison compares the option string coming directly from UI selection via URL and in java code I assign am integer value on the basis of this comparison to render a html table.You are asking me to create seperate jsp pages and include them in main jsp.Now 2 points 1)How I will tell the controller to render particular jsp page in main jsp,there must be some comparison mechanism.2)How effective it would be to maintain  seperate jsp pages instead of using jstl <c:if>condition.